# Is it possible to install Tekton on local system (non container)

Tags: localhost, war, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I want to install Tekton to explore its features and capabilities, I am aware that it is used for CI/CD of cloud native application but our use case is different.
I want to generate a war file using Tekton and deploy it on local liberty server. (I dont want to do any container related stuff), for this I want to keep it simple and install Tekton on local system to understand how can I generate and deploy war file.

Answer (score 1):

Tekton is a project that is based on KNative's (Serverless for Kubernetes) **build** part. It is designed to work in Kubernetes using serverless capabilities as it is in KNative's Sourcing part using scale-to-zero mechanism.

So in short: it is built for running in Kubernetes, it has many k8s native features like installing with operators, running serverless using knative components etc. so you can not use Tekton without Kubernetes.

For giving a try on Tekton on your local you can just install&run minikube on your local and install tekton with operators as explained in the docs. After that you can go for your next step: building a war from your project source.

https://github.com/redhat-developer-demos/tekton-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

### Java code to war

> I want to generate a war file

To build Java code to a war file, it is common to use a Java build tool e.g. Maven, Gradle or Bazel. A build tool can be used locally as well as on a CI/CD system.

### Tekton as CI/CD system

Tekton is a modern CI/CD framework, built for Kubernetes. With Tekton you can design a pipeline, e.g. *Build* - *Test* - *Deploy* - *Integration Tests* - *Deploy to production*.

Tekton drives this pipeline, from step to step, but it **does not** implement the *steps*. A step could be executing Maven, Gradle or Bazel, to build from Java code to a war-file. Since all this is executing in Kubernetes, it is most common to build to a container images so that the application can be excuting in a Kubernetes cluster.

If you are not using a container cluster, there may be other tools than Tekton that solves your problem better.